# How to access JMS statistics in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I understand that JMS has no statistics specs, so there is no standard way of reading things like "count of messages processed", "average time in queue" etc.

I'm looking at two approaches:

1. Access the ActiveMQ statistics directly
2. Maintain statistics in the JMS message consumer

With (1) I'm not finding examples how to get thos stats using Spring Boot. With (2), I'm wondering if the consumer itself needs to maintain the statistics, or if there's a better way.

Does anyone have any working examples?

Comment: Is there a difference between getting stats from ActiveMQ using Spring Boot vs. just normal Java?

Comment: Maintaining statistics in the consumer or acquiring similar stats from the Spring Integration components will only provide you with information from that consumer's perspective. Statistics from the broker will provide a lot more (and different) information. What statistics do you actually need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JMS with Spring integration, its system management features provide statistics that are registered as micrometer metrics in the spring boot app.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#system-management-chapter

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-integration.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html

Comment: This will provide metrics from the ActiveMQ broker?

Comment: No, as far as I know the Spring Integration components track their own statistics, like, e.g. message counts. A Spring Integration JMS inbound channel adapter is (or wraps) a JMS consumer, this would implement approach 2 of the question.

Comment: I don't know what statistics ActiveMQ provides, if that is sufficient Spring Integration metrics might not be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Spring Integration component stats would certainly be helpful in some use-cases, but they are quite different from broker stats (which take into account *every* client, etc.). The original question doesn't really make clear if the Spring Integration component stats would be sufficient or if full broker stats are needed.

Comment: EnableIntegrationManagement is exactly what I was looking for. I was hoping to use Spring JMS stats because then replacing ActiveMQ with RabbitMQ would be much easier (might be a requirement in the future).

Comment: @JustinBertram yes I would expect SI stats and broker stats to be different metrics that would possibly augment each other.

Comment: @Simon, it would have been helpful to make clear in the question that you really only needed consumer-side stats and not actual broker stats. For example, you mentioned "average time in queue" but you'll never be able to get that information from a consumer-side stat, and yet it appears that you don't even really need it.

Comment: You're right, @JustinBertram, my bad. My requirement currently is "can we see some statistics on how the queue is performing", and a message count is apparently enough to make everyone happy right now. Thanks to your help I'll know what adding broker stats like "average queue time" would mean in term of code changes.

Comment: @Simon, the problem is that seeing statistics only from a consumer's perspective won't give you the whole story about how the queue is performing. You need to know how many messages are *in* the queue not just how many are being consumed, and the consumer will never know that unless it asks the broker. The consumer may looks like it's consuming message efficiently but if there's a growing back-log of messages in the queue it puts your broker (and therefore all the consumers) at risk.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, I ended up implementing a broker-specific solution (here: ActiveMQ)

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import javax.jms.*

typealias QueueName = String

@Component
class BrokerFacade(private val connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory) {
    private val statisticsBrokers = mutableMapOf<QueueName, StatisticsBrokerAccess>()

    @Throws(JMSException::class)
    fun getStatistics(queueName: QueueName): QueueStatistics? {
        val brokerAccess = statisticsBrokers.getOrPut(queueName, { StatisticsBrokerAccess(queueName) })
        return brokerAccess.getCurrentStatistics()?.let {
            QueueStatistics(
                queueName,
                it.getLong("size"),
                it.getLong("dequeueCount"),
                it.getDouble("minEnqueueTime"),
                it.getDouble("maxEnqueueTime"),
                it.getDouble("averageEnqueueTime"),
                it.getLong("memoryUsage"),
                it.getLong("memoryPercentUsage")
            )
        }
    }

    inner class StatisticsBrokerAccess(queueName: QueueName) {
        private val statisticsMessageConsumer: MessageConsumer;
        private val statisticsMessageProducer: MessageProducer;
        private val statisticsMessage: Message;

        init {
            val connection = connectionFactory.createConnection()
            connection.start()
            val session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
            val statisticsReplyQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue()
            statisticsMessageConsumer = session.createConsumer(statisticsReplyQueue)
            val statisticsQueue = session.createQueue("ActiveMQ.Statistics.Destination.$queueName")
            statisticsMessageProducer = session.createProducer(statisticsQueue)
            statisticsMessage = session.createMessage()
            statisticsMessage.setJMSReplyTo(statisticsReplyQueue)
        }

        fun getCurrentStatistics(): MapMessage? {
            statisticsMessageProducer.send(statisticsMessage)
            return statisticsMessageConsumer.receive(2000) as MapMessage?
        }
    }
}
```

QueueStatistics is a data class holding the statistic values.